# What is the difference between Azure Resource Manager & Azure API Management?

Tags: azure

- Azure Resource Manager - [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/resource-manager/)
- Azure API Management - [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/api-management/)

Both seem to allow things such as, CRUD on Apps, Database Servers, Databases, or most Azure Resources.

Azure Resource Manager appears Free.
Azure API Management is not.

**What is the fundamental difference between the two?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are completely different things.

Azure Resource Manager is an API and set of tooling for managing Azure resources. When you use the Azure portal to provision or manage resources, under the hood it's all going through ARM.

Azure API Management is a tool for managing *your own* APIs and provides things like proxying, authentication, rate limiting, developer portals etc.

Comment: ARM has an API, API Management manages my own APIs..  Get it, thx..  Both require authentication however.